# Ajax DataUrl To PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am stuck here, i think i am close but not sure.  this is what i have managed to come up with.  Created file input, then resized image then try to upload new image to folder in server.  i think my php script is communicating, but not recieving any image.  here is the code below..

FORM

```
<img src="" id="image">
<input id="input" type="file" onchange="handleFiles()">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
function handleFiles(){
var dataurl = "";
var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('input').files;
var file = filesToUpload[0];

// Create an image
var img = document.createElement("img");
// Create a file reader
var reader = new FileReader();
// Set the image once loaded into file reader
reader.onload = function(e)
{
    img.src = e.target.result;

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    //var canvas = $("<canvas>", {"id":"testing"})[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
    var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
    var width = img.width;
    var height = img.height;

    if (width > height) {
      if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
        width = MAX_WIDTH;
      }
    } else {
      if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
      }
    }
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

    dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");     
}
// Load files into file reader
reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        // Post the data
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("name", "some_filename.jpg");
        fd.append("image", dataurl); // blob file
        fd.append("info", "lah_de_dah");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http:///www.***/upload.php',
            data: fd,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                $('#form_photo')[0].reset();
                location.reload();
}

});
}
</script>
```

SERVER SIDE PHP

```
<?php
$upload_image = $_FILES["image"][ "name" ];
$a = ('" alt="" />');
$folder = "images/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "$folder".$_FILES["image"]["name"]);;

$file = 'images/'.$_FILES["image"]["name"];

$uploadimage = $folder.$_FILES["image"]["name"];
$newname = $_FILES["image"]["name"];

$msg = '';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$a = ('" alt="" />');
$image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$img = file_get_contents($image);
$con = mysqli_connect('**','**','**','**') or die('Unable To connect');
$sql = ("INSERT into links (hyper_links) VALUES('<img src=\"\https://www.***/images/".$_FILES['image']['name']."$a')");

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s",$img);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
if($check==1){
    $msg = 'Successfullly UPloaded';
}else{
    $msg = 'Could not upload';
}
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
<?php
echo $msg;
?>
```

My PHP script might out of wack as i originally was resizing image through PHP, so i just removed what i thought was not needed for the example.  The question is i am not sure how to handle the new image to the server.p

Comment: It seems I can't even get JavaScript code working... Is this all code for HTML/JavaScript? I could try to recreate to see how it's going.

Comment: i had to add this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` into the body. I am currently using a html5 program to build my web app

Comment: I also changed `dataurl="null" to dataurl=""`;

Comment: I see. I solved my personal issue with working problems. What makes you think it's partially working right now (in PHP)?

Comment: Just making sure you do have `enctype='multipart/form-data'` on your form?

Comment: Only the fact that the SQL insert is being placed into the database without the image name though. The data supposed to show img src link, that is why I was thinking it was somewhat working with know errors

Answer (score 1):

**First of all:** You shouldn't upload the image as base64. Just send the raw binary instead. So use [canvas.toBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) and maybe some [polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js/)

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
    fd.append('image', blob, 'some_filename.png')
})
```

Otherwise PHP won't notice any $_FILES cuz base64 will be treated as just any other field $_POST field

**Second is just a tip:** you can use `URL.createDataURL` instead of using the FileReader and you probably should use `img.onload` and `img.onerror` also

by ditching the FileReader you just do this:

```
img.onload = function(){
    // paint to canvas
}
img.onerror = function(){
    // meh, not a image
}
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
```

Comment: i was unable to get this to work, probably my use of knowledge, but i should mention that that this needs to work on mobile platform Chrome/safari as it is a web app that i am creating